# Tipar um array do tipo any[] no angular 6

Tags: json, angular, angular-6

Preciso tipar um objeto, para não receber o any[] no agular 6. Bem, no get, eu recebo isso da API:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "itens": [
        [
            {
                "operatorId": "819ee9cc-70b6-44dc-b9e8-afff8705142c",
                "name": "Vera Silva"
            },
            {
                "operatorId": "ccad3b40-c227-425e-b3b1-feedf6cfac2e",
                "name": "Catarina Silva"
            },
            {
                "operatorId": "68781a7b-ac4c-4a85-9f93-36dc5d65d1af",
                "name": "José da Silva"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "message": ""
}
```

Na minha Component eu rebo assim(getAll)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Operator } from '../operator';
import { OperatorService } from '../operator.service';

export interface getOperator{
  Id: string;
  Name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-operators',
  templateUrl: './operators.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./operators.component.css'],
  providers: [OperatorService]
})

export class OperatorsComponent implements OnInit {

   displayedColumns: string[] = ['codigo', 'nome'];

    public message: string;
    public dataSource: any[];

    constructor
    (
        private _operService: OperatorService
    ) 
    {
        //this.message = 'Hello from HomeComponent constructor';
    }

  ngOnInit() {

  this._operService
      .getAll<any[]>()
      .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
        debugger;
        this.dataSource = data.itens
      });
  }
}
```

Observem que meu **dataSource** recebe um array do tipo **any[]**. Isso está fazendo com que minha **mat-table** no meu **html** não seja preenchida. Meu html

```
div>
  <table mat-table [dataSource] = "dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

     <ng-container matColumnDef="codigo">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Codigo </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let oper"> {{oper.Id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="nome">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nome </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let oper"> {{oper.Name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

a idéia seria tipar ao invés de passar um any[], mas não sei como eu faço isso? Criaria no lado Angular uma classe assim:
**error, itens, message**? e colocaria no lugar do Any, tipo:

```
export class Item{
error: boolean;
itens: array de alguma coisa;
message: string;
}
```

seria isso?

**EDIT1**

Seguindo a orientação do colega Gustavo Santos, fiz o seguinte:

```
export class Operation{
    error: boolean;
    itens: Array<Itens[]>;
    message: string;
}

export class Itens{
    objectId: string;
    name: string;
}
```

mas ao instalar na Component, diz que **[ts] Property 'itens' does not exist on type 'Operation[]'**, exatamente aqui:

```
debugger;
this.dataSource = data.itens;
```

Minha Component está assim:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Operator } from '../operator';
import { OperatorService } from '../operator.service';
import { Operation } from '../model/operators/operations';

export interface getOperator{
  Id: string;
  Name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-operators',
  templateUrl: './operators.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./operators.component.css'],
  providers: [OperatorService]
})

export class OperatorsComponent implements OnInit {

   displayedColumns: string[] = ['codigo', 'nome'];

    public message: string;
    public dataSource: Operation[];

    constructor
    (
        private _operService: OperatorService
    ) 
    {        
    }

  ngOnInit() {

  this._operService
      .getAll<Operation[]>()
      .subscribe((data: Operation[]) => {
        debugger;
        this.dataSource = data.itens;
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O ideal é sempre tipar, você está no caminho certo, se seguir o seu JSON, você tem que ter essas classes:

```
export class Operation {
    error:   boolean;
    items:   Array<Item[]>;
    message: string;
}

export class Item {
    operatorId: string;
    name:       string;
}
```

E quando você der o this._operService.getAll(), substitui por:

```
this._operService.getAll<Operation>()
```

Comment: Tem algumas coisas que ainda não peguei, por exemplo. Eu crio uma pasta chamada **model** e dentro dessa outra pasta  chamada **operators**. Agora dentro da pasta  operators eu crio essas duas classes. Como fica o import em meu **Component**?

Comment: O import fica exatamente como os outros: import { Operation, Item } from 'o caminho onde estão essas classes'.

Comment: Então, fiz isso e dá erro: **import { Operation, Item} from '../model/operators';**. O erro é: **Can't find module  '../model/operators';*. Já fiz com **app** na frente, com **./** ou **../../** e mesmo assim continua com erros. Como faço esse import?

Comment: faltou o operations que é o arquivo que contem a classe. Funcionou

Comment: Isso, tem que informar o nome do arquivo nos imports também, o ideal é deixar uma classe por arquivo. :D Se a sua dúvida foi respondida, dê a resposta como certa por gentileza. :)

Comment: Ainda não consegui testar, Gustavo. Fiz uma edição. Fique tranquilo que marcarei asiim que testar.

Comment: Não populei a mat-table, mas a pergunta foi outra e pela pergunta, está ok sua resposta. Vou fazer outro post